# MOSS Scheduling Simulator (First in Last out) Algorithm

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to implement a First in Last out Algorithm for the given java class and I am slightly confused about how to approach the problem.

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.*;

public class SchedulingAlgorithm {

  public static Results Run(int runtime, Vector processVector, Results result) {
    int i = 0;
    int comptime = 0;
    int currentProcess = 0;
    int previousProcess = 0;
    int size = processVector.size();
    int completed = 0;
    String resultsFile = "Summary-Processes";

    result.schedulingType = "Batch (Nonpreemptive)";
    result.schedulingName = "First-Come First-Served"; 
    try {
      //BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(resultsFile));
      //OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(resultsFile);
      PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(resultsFile));
      sProcess process = (sProcess) processVector.elementAt(currentProcess);
      out.println("Process: " + currentProcess + " registered... (" + process.cputime + " " + process.ioblocking + " " + process.cpudone + " " + process.cpudone + ")");
      while (comptime < runtime) {
        if (process.cpudone == process.cputime) {
          completed++;
          out.println("Process: " + currentProcess + " completed... (" + process.cputime + " " + process.ioblocking + " " + process.cpudone + " " + process.cpudone + ")");
          if (completed == size) {
            result.compuTime = comptime;
            out.close();
            return result;
          }

          for (i = 0; i < size + 1; i++) {
            process = (sProcess) processVector.elementAt(i);
            if (process.cpudone < process.cputime) { 
              currentProcess = i;
            }
          }

          process = (sProcess) processVector.elementAt(currentProcess);
          out.println("Process: " + currentProcess + " registered... (" + process.cputime + " " + process.ioblocking + " " + process.cpudone + " " + process.cpudone + ")");
        }      
        if (process.ioblocking == process.ionext) {
          out.println("Process: " + currentProcess + " I/O blocked... (" + process.cputime + " " + process.ioblocking + " " + process.cpudone + " " + process.cpudone + ")");
          process.numblocked++;
          process.ionext = 0; 
          previousProcess = currentProcess;

          for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            process = (sProcess) processVector.elementAt(i);
            if (process.cpudone < process.cputime && previousProcess != i) { 
              currentProcess = i;
            }
          }

          process = (sProcess) processVector.elementAt(currentProcess);
          out.println("Process: " + currentProcess + " registered... (" + process.cputime + " " + process.ioblocking + " " + process.cpudone + " " + process.cpudone + ")");
        }        
        process.cpudone++;       
        if (process.ioblocking > 0) {
          process.ionext++;
        }
        comptime++;
      }
      out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { /* Handle exceptions */ }
    result.compuTime = comptime;
    return result;
  }
}
```

The goal of the new algorithm is to change the output of the processes file so that process 2 is processed first, followed process 1 and 0. The issue is that I cannot seem to find any written examples of a (First in Last out) scheduling Algorithm.

I have tried to modify the for loops in the algorithm to include a stack.push() for the currentprocess. currentprocess in this case, I believe is the value that indicates what process # is being evaluated by the program to print out the summary-results file like so.

```
for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            process = (sProcess) processVector.elementAt(i);
            if (process.cpudone < process.cputime && previousProcess != i) { 
              currentProcess = i;
              stack.push(currentProcess)
            }
          }
```

Unfortunately, the results will still look like this. And the processes will always output and complete 0 first in the scheduling.

```
Scheduling Type: Batch (Nonpreemptive)
Scheduling Name: First-Come First-Served
Simulation Run Time: 2955
Mean: 1100
Standard Deviation: 510
Process #   CPU Time    IO Blocking CPU Completed   CPU Blocked
0       639 (ms)    30 (ms)     639 (ms)    21 times
1       1158 (ms)   30 (ms)     1158 (ms)   38 times
2       1158 (ms)   30 (ms)     1158 (ms)   38 times
```

If you have anymore questions please let me know, as I am trying to rapidly complete this assignment. I will be thankful for any advice I could receive regarding this problem.

Comment: I have found that adding:```int currentProcess = processVector.size() - 1;``` allows us to have process of index 2 to be out put first. Due to the natural flow of the existing algorithm our First-In registered value 2 is also output last. I am not sure if this counts as a FILO algorithm, but so far it has been the closest I have been able to manipulate this function.

Comment: For all those who may have to deal with this simulator in the future, I have just discovered that the change that I have made is correct. Therefore, I am closing this thread. Thank you to all who may have shown interest in observing this post.